# foreground service is getting killed in redmi 8a dual? Any solution?

Tags: java, android, class, web-services

**I need to make my service unstoppable** did not kill when the app removes from the taskbar or the device screen off. any permanent solution for this. I tried the foreground service but after the device screen OFF the foreground, the service was killed what I do?

This is my code I have created service and call from main activity

```
    private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
    private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_Id";
    private PendingIntent ButtonOneScreen;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

        startForeground();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    public static void restart(Context context){
        Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(mainIntent);
        System.exit(0);
        //System.exit(1);

    }


    private void startForeground() {

        ;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyApplication.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);



        startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) // don't forget create a notification channel first
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.diis00)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Service is running background")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.diis,"EXIT",null)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build());
    }



    PendingIntent  stopForegroundService() {
        Log.d("TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE", "Stop foreground service.");

        // Stop foreground service and remove the notification.
        stopForeground(true);

        // Stop the foreground service.
        stopSelf();
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: attach your code to question please, the piece of your code that you set the service foreground.

Comment: I attached code for ref